# What is the correct Rails association for this design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Environment: Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.1, Windows 8.1, Devise

I am confused as to how to handle this issue.  I have items that are stored at a location until they are checked out by a user.  I want to be able to query the item and determine which location or which user currently holds it.  So, the item will belong to either a location or a user.  Each location and each user can have many items.

This is something like a large library system where the book could be in one of several buildings and a patron could check out books from each of the buildings.  At any point, I'd like to locate a book as either in the building or with the patron.

My confusion stems mainly from the fact that the item would be associated with either of two different models at different points in time.  It could be at a location or it could be held by a user, and should never be both.

What association or design would work for this?  Thanks....

Comment: I totally disagree on the hold on this one.  It's very specific.  The only thing that I didn't include was the model/migration code which isn't written because I am doing the design.  Please release the hold immediately because I need the advice.

Comment: I can also point out a list of very similar questions that were permitted and answered in this forum.

Comment: I can probably answer this question, take it off hold and I'll give it a shot

Comment: you can check on rails's polymorphic associations

Comment: Polymorphic is looking correct, if he opens this up so that it can be appropriately answered.  Because, you'd think that an question that could be answered so clearly must have been written clearly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a polymorphic association with this, try something like this:

Item.rb

```
  belongs_to :check_outer, :polymorphic => true
```

User.rb

```
  has_many :items, :as => :check_outer
```

Location.rb

```
  has_many :items, :as => :check_outer
```

You will need the proper database columns to support this.

- On the `items` table, add `check_outer_type:string` and `check_outer_id:int`

For more information on polymorphic associations, check this out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: I'd probably only add that, if you want to be able to determine the location as requested, you need both a foreign key column and a type column in the item definition.  This would allow @item.check_outer to be resolved, which I need.

Comment: Thanks R_G I forgot to add that you need the necessary migrations, I'll edit